# List of Checkbox returns false even when checked in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

Student Attendance class

```
 public class StudentAttendance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsPresent { get; set; }

}
```

View table for my attendance form

```
 @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
          {
            <tr>
                <td> @student.FullName</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="HiddenID" id="id" value="@student.StudentID"/></td>
                <td ><label class="col-form-label"><input type="checkbox" name="IsPresent" ></label></td> </tr> }
```

Attendance Page Model

```
 [BindProperty]
    public StudentAttendance studentAttendance { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<int> StudentAttendanceList { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int? SearchClassID { get; set; }


    [BindProperty]
    public List<int> HiddenID { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public bool IsPresent { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

Attenadance On Post()

```
foreach (var id in HiddenID)
        {
            Conn.StudentAttendance.Add(new StudentAttendance
            {
                StudentID = id,
                IsPresent = IsPresent,
            });
        }
```

When i submit and save the IsPresent value remains false even when checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the IsPresent in the form is not bound to the Model, and the default value of IsPresent in the model is false. Finally, it obtained false each time. By dynamically changing the value in the checkbox through a JavaScript function, the corresponding selected id can be submitted to the background.

In Attendance.cshtml

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
        {
            <tr>
        
                <td> @student.FullName </td>
                <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="HiddenID" id="id" value="@student.StudentID" /></td>
                <td>
                    <label class="col-form-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="IsPresent" name="isPresent" value="false" onchange="changePresent(event,@student.StudentID)">
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="sub" />
</form>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function changePresent(e,id) {
        if (e.target.value=='true') {
            e.target.value = false
        }
        else {
            console.log('-=-=')
            e.target.value = id
        }
    }
</script>
}
```

Then, in post method, get the checked id, and justify whether the id is checked.

```
public void OnPost(int[] isPresent)
        {
            foreach (var id in HiddenID)
            {
                new StudentAttendance
                {
                    StudentID = id,
                    IsPresent = id == isPresent[id - 1],
                };
                /*Conn.StudentAttendance.Add(new StudentAttendance
                {
                    StudentID = id,
                    IsPresent = IsPresent,
                });*/
            }
        }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Yiyi You, i really do appreciate, but i got an exception error: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: Please i will really appreciate if you can help me further i am getting   IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array error

Comment: I think the issue you mentioned in the case can be  solved by the code,If you have a new exception,you can create a new thread,debug and tell where you get the Exception,and which data you pass to get the Exception.